# Cloud datastore - How to set indexes for my query filters with any column values?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

First of all, apologies if my question isn't precise.
 I am using filters in my html template which runs query on any column values which are filled in. For instance, I filter my list by year and range leaving other fields empty. (refer snap below)
[image]

It throws me an error:[image]

My index.yaml code is:

```
indexes:
- kind: car
    properties:
      - name: ev_manufacturer
      - name: ev_year
      - name: ev_battery_size
      - name: ev_power
      - name: ev_range
      - name: ev_cost
```

What should I set in the index.yaml file so that I can use query filter with any of the car features?

Comment: Based on your error logs, you haven't defined an index for the query filter `ev_year` `ev_range` that you're using. Can you try to specify a new query filter for just the two query filters and test if it works? @LibinThomas

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have a look at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/optimize-indexes to give yourself some insight into Datastore indexing and how to use composite indexes across multiple queries.

However, in the case of multiple filters, you may only have one inequality, and it looks like you might be intending to have inequalities on multiple fields, but unclear what your queries are. You probably want to consider switching from inequality queries to strict equality queries.  E.g. store ev_range as accurate_range (float), and ev_range (enum) and provide ranges fro the enum value, e.g. RANGE_400_TO_600KM, RANGE_600_1000KM.